# Oracle - grant privileges to a user

Tags: oracle, privileges, sql-grant

Is there a way to grant privileges of select, insert, update and delete to a user so that if we add a new table later, the user still have these privileges on the new table ?

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest and dirtiest way to go about something like this is to create a trigger on all create table statements in the DB, and then granting privileges on tables fitting your pre-defined conditions.

However, I don't see why not to add a grant command to every create table command ran in the system.
Bear in mind that DDLs and grant commands are not something to be taken lightly. Designing your schema and its privileges should be done with careful thought, and automating is a recipe for problems further down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a recommended practice for security reasons on a development instance this is acceptable

> grant select, insert, update, delete any table to your_user;

I stress again that this allows that user access to any table in any schema except SYS and is not a best practice.